# ASP Time formatting - Change default formatting?

Tags: sql, date, asp-classic, time

I'm working on an ASP (Classic) application using MS SQL as database.
In the database I got 2 values storen StartTime and EndTime

```
StartTime                   EndTime
1899-12-30 09:30:00.000     1899-12-30 17:00:00.000
```

The thing is, when I read those values from the database and write them on my page

```
rsSessions.fields.getValue("StartTime")
```

I get the following result:

> 09:30:00 AM
>
> 05:00:00 PM

While I would need a normal short 24h format.
It seems to me that ASP formats the time by itself here, is there any way to disable this without having to change the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has to do with the locale of the server. ASP Classic formats numbers, currency and dates accordingly.

You can setup a specific locale by using:

```
Session.LCID = [locale]
```

See [ASP LCID Property](http://www.w3schools.com/asp/prop_lcid.asp) for some more info. A list with locales can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/goglobal/bb964664).

For my own code I tend to convert a string to a date:

```
dim rawDate : rawDate = cDate(value)
```

After that I can decompose the date and assemble it in any way I need. Take a look at the [Date/Time Functions](http://www.w3schools.com/vbscript/vbscript_ref_functions.asp) here.

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
FormatDateTime ( cdate(rsSessions("StartTime") ), 4)
```

4 = vbShortTime - Return time: hh:mm